# Assignment Statement Cuts off Characters

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I can successfully compile, but when I go to run my program, it throws an error telling me that a DLL does not exist.  After trial and error, I determined that the program was looking for a DLL in "ROGRAM FILES\FolderName\rrpd.dll"  obviously cutting off the first four characters of the folder.

This is for an application called R&R Report Writer which has been around for 25+ years and has never had this problem before.

Debugging, I determined that the error comes from an assignment statement in the program module EXPLMGR.CPP (explicit library manager):

```
CString CExplicitLibraryManager::FindLocalDllFile(CString csDllName) const
{
ASSERT( csDllName.Find('\\') == -1 );  // These names should not have directory stuff. 
// Search for the file in the program directory directory. 
// If not found there, search in the registry system. 
// If not found in either location, just return the file name. 
CString csDllPath = m_csAppDirectory + csDllName ;
BOOL bDllExists = DoesFileExist ( csDllPath ) ;  // Don't bother calling DoesDllExist(). A path is provided.
if ( !bDllExists )
{
    csDllPath = m_csRrSystemDirectory + csDllName ;
    bDllExists = DoesFileExist ( csDllPath ) ;
    if ( !bDllExists )
    {
        // Must call the FindWindowsFile() here so that we can guarentee to return the full pathname. 
        csDllPath = FindWindowsFile ( csDllName ) ;
        bDllExists = DoesFileExist ( csDllPath ) ;
    }
}
if ( bDllExists )
{
    CFileStatus fsFile ;
    CFile::GetStatus ( csDllPath, fsFile ) ;
    //TRACE( "CExplicitLibraryManager::FindLocalDllFile()  Reports the DLL to be %s\n", fsFile.m_szFullName ) ;

    csDllPath = fsFile.m_szFullName ;
}
return csDllPath ;
}
```

specifically, the line 4 up from the bottom:

```
csDllPath = fsFile.m_szFullName ;
```

At this point, fsFile.m_szFullName is "C:\PROGRAM FILES\FolderName\rrpd.dll", csDllPath is the same thing as well.

Debugging and hitting [F11], the assignment dives right into

```
c:\program files\Microsoft visual studio\vc98\mfc\src\strcore.cpp
```

and the section is:

```
const CString& CString::operator=(LPCTSTR lpsz)
{
ASSERT(lpsz == NULL || AfxIsValidString(lpsz));
AssignCopy(SafeStrlen(lpsz), lpsz);
return *this;
}
```

And immediately, if I mouse over lpsz, its value is now

```
"rogram files\FolderName\rrpd.dll"
```

Is there any way to address this?  What additional information can I provide?

Comment: My first thought would be to Rebuild All, if you haven't already.

Comment: What @RichieHindle said.  This looks like the result of mixing debug and non-debug libraries.

Comment: I have rebuilt all, both in the release and debug configs.  I'm not sure what you mean about debug / non-debug libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that in experimenting on making the program 64-bit compatible, the m_size element in the CFileStatus struct was changed to ULONGLONG from LONG in the AFX.H file.  The problem laid dormant for several builds but finally blew up with the most recent.  Not sure why.  Anyway, I changed the declaration back to LONG and it appears to be working properly now.

Comment: Woah... wait a second there... you changed **which** declaration "back" to `LONG` from `ULONGLONG`? *Please* tell me you didn't edit the `afx.h` file!

Comment: `CFileStatus::m_size` has been a `ULONGLONG` for a long time (since at least VS 2003). It sounds like your program might be linking to libraries built with/for VC6 where that field had a type of `LONG` (I'm not sure what the type of that field was in VS 2002 - I can't convince that program to install on my Win7 box).  I think you need to do some analysis regarding what libraries are used throughout the program/product. You certainly shouldn't be patching the library headers without understanding why they don't seem to be working in your build.

Comment: We're still using VS98 (VC++ 6)